# i am trying to read a file in c language the file structure is in array and i have to seperate it into array x[] and y[]

Tags: c

My code is to find line number and then print all element in it but it is throwing garbage value and main thing to do is to seperate front one as x and y respectively plese help me seperate x[] = [60,15,62.....] and y[] = [229,221,59,....]

Dataset is

```
60,229
15,221
62,59
96,120
16,97
41,290
52,206
...
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    FILE *myFile;
    myFile = fopen("datasetLR1.txt", "r");
    int count=0;
    char c;
    for (c = getc(myFile); c != EOF; c = getc(myFile)) {
        if (c == '\n'){
            count = count + 1; 
        }// Increment count if this character is newline 
            
    }
    
    int numberArray[count*2];
    int i;

    if (myFile == NULL){
        printf("Error Reading File\n");
        exit (0);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < count*2; i++){
        fscanf(myFile, "%d,", &numberArray[i] );
    }

    for (i = 0; i < count*2; i++){
        printf("Number is: %d\n\n", numberArray[i]);
    }

    fclose(myFile);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (myFile == NULL)` I hope that's never true, since you completely ignored checking that very condition *prior* to the previous loop. However, your file *is* at EOF when exiting that loop, and you did nothing to change that condition (i.e. rewind). And since your `fscanf` calls are never verified (the return value of that function is provided for a reason; use it), your code is oblivious to the `2*count` number of failed scans from a file pointer sitting at EOF the entire time.

Answer (score 1):

After you count the number of lines in the file with your first for loop, you should use `rewind(myFile);`. This puts you back to the beginning of the file. Without this, you are reading off the end of the file, which is producing the garbage values. Other than that, your code works fine.

You should also look at doing `fscanf("%d,%d\n", &x, &y);`, which should read off both numbers at once (and the newline) and assign them to x and y respectively. This should simplify your code significantly, however, your code works fine without it.

Comment: you mean ` &x, &y`